# Что лучше и быстрее сравнивать int или string?

Tags: mysql, база-данных, if, типы-данных, производительность

Есть форма где по разным параметрам составляется номер и база данных на mysql, в который хранятся данные с привязкой к номеру. После отправки формы  PHP составляет номер и ищет нужный номер в базе данных и выводим данные.

Что лучше использовать для `WHERE nomer = '$nomer'` в плане быстродействия int или string и как лучше строить готовый номер из полученных (быстродействие)?

Например, из формы пришло `[1,2,3]` нужно получить 123. Первое, что приходить в голову - конкатенация строк, а потом перевод в int. 
Дело чисто в спортивном интересе.

Comment: Попробовать оба варианта и сравнить - лень?

Comment: Не знаю как проверить на быстродействие оба варианта ><

Comment: Мне почему то кажется, что int

Comment: нее, лучше abst

Comment: `int` должен быть быстрее, но если у Вас изначально строка, то ее преобразование в `int` аннулирует всю потенциальную выгоду.

Comment: @Yaant этот комментарий мог бы быть хорошим ответом.

Answer (score 1):

Лучший вариант сравнения это

```
int
```